# Visual FoxPro OleDB

Tags: oledb, foxpro

I have a Visual FoxPro database that I was able to connect to just fine in Access using ODBC. Now I have been "upgraded" to Windows 7 and cannot figure out a way to get at the data. I understand that ODBC won't work and so I downloaded and installed the FoxPro OleDB provider. Using the OleDB connection wizard in Excel I go through the steps to connect then when it goes to get the data I get an error message "Data could not be retrieved from the database". In Visual Web Developer, I go through the process to connect but when I click on the Data Links button VWD crashes and exits. Is there some non-Microsoft solution or do I have to go find an XP box and convert everything into something I can use?

Comment: These links might help, the ODBC FoxPro driver seems to be only available for 32bits on W7:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/6f5141f8-ae54-4ce7-b47d-cd297900d5e7

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/82470976-e80c-4f11-b0f0-cdf39433d104

Hope this helps.

Comment: What language are you trying to work with, or are you just relying on Visual Web Developer (not familiar with that).  However, for years I've used the VFP OleDb provider, almost everything I've done works without problems.

Comment: Also, which version of Visual Web Developer are you running.

Comment: You certainly can use the OleDB driver under Windwos 7, 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: I can't find the FoxPro ODBC driver anywhere on microsoft.com to try it on my 32-bit Win7. Excel comes closest with OleDB, giving me a list of tables to import into a spreadsheet, then fails with a typical terse non informative error message. Can't get this far in VWD 2010 because there is a bug that makes it crash when I click on Data Links. If I could find a copy of the old ODBC driver i will try it.

Comment: Okay, found a copy of VFPODBC.MSI someone had stored on their website and got it to work. Thank you folks for steering me back to working with ODBC.